# DynamoDBMappingException: could not convert attribute

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

Receiving an exception saving a complicated object to DDB:

`Caused by: com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMappingException: Cohort[students]; could not convert attribute`
`com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapperTableModel.convert(DynamoDBMapperTableModel.java:249)`

Here is my record, suspect something is wrong with my DynamoDBDocument but every field has a getter and a setter. It could also be with trying to use ArrayList?

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "ClassroomTable")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Classroom {

    @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "ClassID")
    private String classID;

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "Teacher")
    private String teacher;

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "Cohort")
    public Cohort cohort;

    @Data
    @DynamoDBDocument
    public static class Cohort {
        public ArrayList<Student> students;
    }
    @Data
    public static class Student {
        public StudentInfo studentInfo;

        @Data
        public static class StudentInfo{
            public String name;
            public Integer grade;
            public Integer age;

     } 
}
```

I have seen similar issues with uncovert but this isn't the exact same. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception is pointing to the error, there is something wrong with the field `students` inside the class `Cohort`.

I guess the type `ArrayList` is not supported. According to [Supported data types for DynamoDB Mapper for Java](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.DataTypes.html):

> DynamoDB supports the Java Set, List, and Map collection types.

Also, it is a good practice to use the collection interfaces and not the concrete implementations, in this case use `List` instead of `ArrayList`.

Another point that could cause issues is that the classes `Student` and `StudentInfo` do not have the `@DynamoDBDocument` annotation. See the example in [Java Annotations for DynamoDB - DynamoDBDocument](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.Annotations.html#DynamoDBMapper.Annotations.DynamoDBDocument).

Comment: I did end up solving it. ArrayLists are supported but the issue was indeed that the nested classes did not have the @DynamoDBDocument which led to the DDBMapper not recognizing them.